# Validate form before button click

Tags: php, javascript

I have a form on the contact page which i want to validate before the user clicks the submit button.

```
<form id="contact" name="f1" action="mail.php" onsubmit="validate()">
```

I have Javascript code which does validation of fields. But, when i click on the button the  user is redirected to 'mail.php' without doing validation.

Comment: Post the code wich you used in the form tag

Comment: Well kishan show us what you have tried first. Show some codes, how are we supposed to see whats wrong???

Comment: I think you want to validate each of the field in the form before user click on it. Isn't it?

Comment: I think when i click on the submit button two events are triggerd; one is javascript function being called and the other one is action attribute in the form tag. I have tried many examples from web but all went in vain. How do i resolve the conflict between two events?

Answer (score 2):

```
<form id="contact" name="f1" action="mail.php" onsubmit="return validate();">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<form id="contact" name="f1" action="mail.php" onsubmit="return validate();">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple example http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you have a validation function then do something like

```
If (validation()){
    $('form').submit();
}
```

Comment: <form id="form_487195" name="f1" class="appnitro" method="post" action="Mail.php" onSubmit="return validator()>                          I have javascript code containing validator() method placed right after the ending form tag. When i click on the submit button it goes to mail.php page

Answer (score 0):

javascript onclick event calls the function only
but if you try return function()
then if the function returns true then only the form is submitted.

another approach can be to use a validation variable

```
var validate = true
if( ...validation condition fails ... )
{
validate = false
}

if (validate)
{
$('#formID').submit();
}
```